# Self-intersection of an axis

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Let $X$ be a projective, smooth curve over an algebraically closed field, $Y = X\times X$ and $\mathcal{l}= pt\times X$ where $pt$ is a closed point of $X$. Can one say that the intersection number $\mathcal{l}^2$ is equal to zero by arguing that applying a translation to $\mathcal{l}$ moves it in its equivalence class so that they do not meet?

Is there a better way to see this? I am using the "usual" definition of the intersection number as found in Hartshorne Ch. V.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The intersection number is zero. Your use of the word `translation' though can be confusing. Any point $p\in X$ is rationally equivalent to a divisor $D$ with $p\not\in\mathrm{Supp}\, D$ and then $p\times X\sim D\times X$.

Comment: @Mohan Could you expand on your assertion of the equivalence please?

Comment: If $E$ is rationally equivalent to $F$, two divisors on a smooth projective surface, then they are numerically equivalent, so their intersection with any other divisor yield the same number. If $E$ is disjoint from another divisor, then their intersection is zero.

Comment: Thank you, @Mohan. This is clear, what I meant to ask is why is $p\times X$ rationally equivalent to $D\times X$ for some divisor $D$ with $p\notin \operatorname{Supp} D$? Is this because there always exist a rationl function with $p$ as a zero or pole?

Comment: Yes, there is always a rational function with a (say) simple pole at $p$.